# Counting Null rows between non Null values

Tags: sql-server, mysql, oracle, query

I have a table that counts logins to a website with the first column, USER_ID, being the user's unique identifier. The next column is a list of months in the date format %m/%d/%Y, and the next column is a date which indicates whether or not that person logged into the website during that month.
What I want to generate is a 4th column that counts NULL values between non-NULL values for that 3rd column.

My question is: given the first 3 columns below, how would I write a query that generates the 4th column?

[image]

Comment: Tag you question with the DBMS you are actually using. The solution may vary by DBMS product.

Comment: Show SOURCE tables DDLs, sample data in them, and desured result for this data. As a fiddle or as scripts text, not as a picture. And specify ONE DBMS, including its version.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a column which is the rolling count of the login column (because `COUNT(Login)` won’t include nulls. Then have a rolling count (less one) of that column, partitioned by it too (aka `ROW_NUMBER()`). This second column will reset to zero every time you have a login value, but will be able to keep increasing in between. All these should also be partitioned by the User, and you may want to do something special when `COUNT(Login)` is zero, because that will be the time before the user has logged in (so maybe use `CASE` for that).